# Measurable linear functionals on a B-space are continuous?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, banach-spaces, weak-topology

Let $(X,\tau_+)$ be a Banach space, consider $\tau_-$ the weakest topology such that all linear $\tau_+$-continuous functional are continuous with respect to $\tau_-$, finally consider $\Sigma_+$ (respectively $\Sigma_-$) the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\tau_+$ (respectively $\tau_-$). Within this setup I have two questions

> Is $\Sigma_-$ the smallest $\sigma$-algebra such that all $\Sigma_+$-measurable linear functional are measurable ?

> Are all $\Sigma_-$-measurable linear functional $\tau_-$-continuous ?

---

Some thoughts :

It is clear that the set of $\tau_-$-continuous linear functionals is the same as the set of $\tau_+$-continuous linear functionals. If the first point mentioned above is true, then the set of $\Sigma_-$-measurable linear functionals and the set of $\Sigma_+$-measurable linear functionals are also the same and therefore the second point is equivalent to

> Are all $\Sigma_+$-measurable linear functional $\tau_+$-continuous ?

In other-words, is any measurable (w.r.t. the Borel $\sigma$-algebra) linear functional on a B-space continuous ?

---

I have this feeling that the second point is false unless we add boundedness :

> Are all bounded $\Sigma_-$-measurable linear functional $\tau_-$-continuous ?

which would be also very interesting to study.

Comment: Maybe, Schwartz's Borelian Graph Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_graph_theorem 
helps.